# netcat in shell script giving invalid connection

Tags: shell, webserver, netcat

I have a shell script that uses `netcat` to listen to `localhost` on port 1111 for web requests. Every time I try accessing `localhost:1111/index.html` for example I get:

```
invalid connection to [127.0.0.1] from localhost [127.0.0.1] 60038
```

the number at the end (60038) seems to be increasing every time I access `localhost`.

Any suggestions on what's going wrong? And what is the `default localhost` directory? Where should I put an `index.html` so that `localhost:1111/index.html` would work?

EDIT

here is the full script:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true
do
netcat -vvl localhost -p 1111 -c '
    set -x
    read http_request
    echo HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    echo
    echo "Received HTTP request: $http_request"
'   
done
```

Comment: The number at the end is the source port, which is randomly chosen; that's the port used by your browser to open the outgoing request. Don't worry about it.  Can you post your `netcat` command line?  Is the 'invalid connection' message coming from `netcat` or another tool?

Comment: I just added the full script. I'm not sure if netcat is giving the message, it may be set. I'm not sure what set even does though!

Comment: That script is the listening side.  Can you also post the client side?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your original script requires that the connection comes from a host named `localhost`, but for some reason that filtering is failing. Unusual, because it matches exactly the name listed in the error: `invalid connection to [127.0.0.1] from localhost [127.0.0.1] 60038`

This command will listen on the `localhost` network interface (and will ignore requests from other interfaces, like your LAN):

```
netcat -vvl -s localhost -p 1111 -c '
    set -x
    read http_request
    echo HTTP/1.0 200 OK
    echo
    echo "Received HTTP request: $http_request"
'
```

If you want to listen for requests on all interfaces, you can drop the `-s` part altogether:

```
netcat -vvl -p 1111 -c '...'
```

On my system, if I want to do the same kind of source host filtering without `-s`, I need to use either `127.0.0.1` or `localhost.localdomain`:

```
netcat -vvl localhost.localdomain -p 1111 -c '...'

netcat -vvl 127.0.0.1 -p 1111 -c '...'
```

In any case, one of the above options should work for you:

```
$ netcat -vvl 127.0.0.1 -p 1111 -c '
quote>     set -x
quote>     read http_request
quote>     echo HTTP/1.0 200 OK
quote>     echo
quote>     echo "Received HTTP request: $http_request"
quote> '
listening on [any] 1111 ...
connect to [127.0.0.1] from localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1] 35368
+ read http_request
+ echo HTTP/1.0 200 OK
+ echo
+ echo Received HTTP request: GET / HTTP/1.1
$
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! changing localhost to 127.0.0.1 seemed to do the trick on firefox. Chrome is handling things differently I guess.